# Why RegExp generates an error of "unexpected quantifier" on IE8?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a Javascript error that have been reported to me and unfortunately I've no idea on how to reproduce it. IE8 Developer Tools reports the following error: *Unexpected quantifier*. The following row produces the error:

```
var g=RegExp(d+"=([^|]*)").exec(j); //output from closure-compiler
```

I guess I have to escape properly the pipe like that (`\\|`) to fix the problem, but I don't know if I'm right because I don't know how to reproduce the error.

Any suggestions or solutions are welcome.

Thanks.

[UPDATE]

The values of `d` are the keys of `__utmz` cookie values which I'm trying to retrieve and they are listed in an array like this `["utmccn", "utmcmd", /* ... */]`. Well now there's not so much I can do, I'm at home with my friend the flu.

Comment: the unexpected quantifier is probably coming from the value of variable d, as there is nothing wrong with the rest of that regex

Comment: I assume if you can't reproduce the error, the logic that generates d should be looked at more closely. Why don't you post that logic?

Comment: similar problem and relative solution, hope can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137741/how-to-escape-a-regex-that-generates-an-error-of-unexpected-quantifieron-ie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "quantifier" is a regular expression operator like `*` or `+`.  The variable "d" in the above code probably contains something that's being interpreted as "code" to the regular expression parser, and it's invalid. You're right that it needs to be appropriately escaped. It's a problem very similar to the problem of escaping text that's being included in HTML markup, but distinct because the syntax in question is completely different (that is, regular expression syntax vs. HTML syntax).

There are a lot of special characters in regular expression syntax, obviously, so it'll take a pretty gnarly regex to do that. Here's a possible way to do such a thing:

```
var quoted = unquoted.replace(/([*+.?|\\\[\]{}()])/g, '\\$1');
```

That might not get all of them; I'd look around for code that's more definitely tested than something a dope like me just made up :-)

Since that code you posted looks like it may come from some library, you may want to check the stack trace from the IE debugger to find out where the problem starts.

Comment: The strange thing is that all `d` values are already defined one by one by me, and these values are all `[a-z]`. The sad thing is that all I have of that IE stack trace is a jpeg sent through another 2 guys saying *There is an error of "Unexpected quantifier" at this point in the code... Fix it!*

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule you should always escape special characters inside character classes, you never know when you run into a regexp engine that will fail.

Comment: Aside from the universal metacharacter (backslash), only `^`, `-`, `]`, and sometimes `[` have special meanings inside character classes.  They can be a little confusing because their special meanings sometimes depend on their position (e.g. `[]]` matches a `]` in .NET, but it's a syntax error in Java), but I've never heard of a regex flavor treating `[^|]` as anything but "anything but a pipe".