# How to resolve an unexpected quantifier in Javascript regex pattern?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, client-side-validation, customvalidator

**Scenario:**
I've added a client side url validator using the following regex pattern. The pattern is supposed to check whether the URL input matches.

```
^(?#Protocol)(?:(?:ht|f)tp(?:s?)\:\/\/|~\/|\/)?(?#Username:Password)(?:\w+:\w+@)?(?#Subdomains)(?:(?:[-\w]+\.)+(?#TopLevel Domains)(?:com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum|travel|[a-z]{2}))(?#Port)(?::[\d]{1,5})?(?#Directories)(?:(?:(?:\/(?:[-\w~!$+|.,=]|%[a-f\d]{2})+)+|\/)+|\?|#)?(?#Query)(?:(?:\?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)(?:&(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)*)*(?#Anchor)(?:#(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)?$
```

**Issue:**

When I debug the `ValidateOtherInstituteWebsite` JavaScript method via IE, a `JavaScript runtime error - unexpected quantifier` error is thrown.

**Checks:**

I implemented the same regex in my C# server side validation method with no error, and the regex matches appropriately. From researching the error it seems the compiler is [interpreting some of the regex as code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923652/why-regexp-generates-an-error-of-unexpected-quantifier-on-ie8), but I don't see where.

**Question:**

How can this regex pattern be edited to work with JavaScript?

**Code:**

```
function ValidateOtherInstituteWebsite(sender, args) {

    var valid = false;

    alert("debug alert");
    var otherInstituteWebsiteText = $("#vs_institutewebsite").text();
    var otherInstituteWebsiteUrl = otherInstituteWebsiteText;

    var urlValidationRegex = new RegExp("^(?#Protocol)(?:(?:ht|f)tp(?:s?)\:\/\/|~\/|\/)?(?#Username:Password)(?:\w+:\w+@)?(?#Subdomains)(?:(?:[-\w]+\.)+(?#TopLevel Domains)(?:com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum|travel|[a-z]{2}))(?#Port)(?::[\d]{1,5})?(?#Directories)(?:(?:(?:\/(?:[-\w~!$+|.,=]|%[a-f\d]{2})+)+|\/)+|\?|#)?(?#Query)(?:(?:\?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)(?:&(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)*)*(?#Anchor)(?:#(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)?$");

    if (urlValidationRegex.test(otherInstituteWebsiteUrl))
    {
        valid = true;
    }

    args.IsValid = valid;

}
```

*Exception screen shot:*

[image]

Comment: My... This regex... How can you maintain that ? In any case one of the problems is that you pasted into quotes a regex without the proper escapings. You must make it a regex literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS regex does not support comments like `(?#...)` that can be used in regex flavors that support freespace (`/x`, verbose) mode, you need to remove all of them.

Use

```
var urlValidationRegex = /^(?:(?:ht|f)tp(?:s?):\/\/|~\/|\/)?(?:\w+:\w+@)?(?:(?:[-\w]+\.)+(?:com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum|travel|[a-z]{2}))(?::[\d]{1,5})?(?:(?:(?:\/(?:[-\w~!$+|.,=]|%[a-f\d]{2})+)+|\/)+|\?|#)?(?:(?:\?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)(?:&(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)*)*(?:#(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)?$/i;
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oC0dD8/1)

I also suggest adding a `/i` case-insensitive modifier.

The only advantage of using a RegExp constructor is that you can easily add comments to blocks of this expression. Then use:

```js
var urlValidationRegex = RegExp("^" + 
      "(?:(?:ht|f)tps?://|~?/)?" + // Protocol
      "(?:\\w+:\\w+@)?" +          //Username:Password
      "(?:(?:[-\\w]+\\.)+" +       //Subdomains
      "(?:com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum|travel|[a-z]{2}))" +                                  //TopLevel Domains
      "(?::\\d{1,5})?" +           //Port
      "(?:(?:(?:/(?:[-\\w~!$+|.,=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})+)+|/)+|\\?|#)?" + //Directories
      "(?:(?:\\?(?:[-\\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\\d{2}])+=?(?:[-\\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})*)(?:&(?:[-\\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\\d{2}])+=?(?:[-\\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})*)*)*" +                                   //Query
      "(?:#(?:[-\\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})*)?$" //Anchor
);
document.body.innerHTML = urlValidationRegex.test("000");
document.body.innerHTML +="<br/>"+ urlValidationRegex.test("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35089817/how-to-resolve-an-unexpected-quantifier-in-javascript-regex-pattern/35089871?noredirect=1#comment57910001_35089871");
```

Comment: The regex is not fine-tuned that much, but can be used as a regex literal, not inside a RegExp constructor, because the backslashes must be doubled in the constructor notation and the `/` slashes do not have to be escaped.

Comment: Okay so what exactly do I have to change on the above regex in order to use it in the RegExp ctor?

Comment: If you do not need to use any variable inside it you do not have to use the constructor notation. MDN RegExp reference advises so. If you want to use it inside a RegExp constructor, you must delete all singlr backslashes before `/`s and double all single backslashes ( `\d` must be written as `\\d` to match a digit).

Comment: I am on a mobile now and cannot help more for the time being.