# regex replace jumbles string

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my console.log:

```
str : <a href="Javascript:PostRating('','|P|622','+0')">+0</a>-D : replace : <a href="Javascript:PostRating('','|P|621','D')">D</a>a href="Javascript:PostRating('','|P|622','+0')">+0</a>-D
```

I have the following function:

```
                function replaceAll_withMatching(str, find, rep, prodId) {
                    //console.log(str + " : " + find + " : " + rep + " : " + prodId);
                    var returnString = "";

                    if (find.toLowerCase() == str.toLowerCase()) {
                        returnString = rep;
                    } else {
                        escfind = "\\" + find ;
                        var regexp = new RegExp(escfind, "i");
                        var match = regexp.test(str);

                        if (match) {
                            var regAHREF = new RegExp("\\<a", "i");
                            var AHREFMatch = regAHREF.test(str);
                            if (AHREFMatch == false) {
                                str = str.replace(regexp, rep);
                                str = replaceProductAll(str, PRODUCT_PLACEHOLD, prodId);
                            } else {
                                var aTagText = $($.parseHTML(str)).filter('a').text();

                                if ((find !== aTagText) && (aTagText.indexOf(find) < 0)) {
                                    console.log(regexp);
                                    console.log("str : " + str + " : replace : " + str.replace(regexp, rep));   
                                    str = str.replace(regexp, rep);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //console.log(str);
                        returnString = str;
                    }

                    //returnString = replaceProductAll(returnString, PRODUCT_PLACEHOLD, prodId);
                    return returnString;
                }
```

This function looks for a "`<a>`" tag, if it doesn't find one then it does the replace.  If it does find one it has some conditions that if everything checks out it does another replace.

The string that I'm passing in has been already "parsed" on the +0:

```
<a href="Javascript:PostRating('','|P|622','+0')">+0</a>-D
```

In the second pass I'm expecting it to find the "D" in the above string,  and then do the following replacement:

```
<a href="Javascript:PostRating('','|P|621','D')">D</a>
```

But as you can see, after the 2nd replace it is jumbling the string and producing malformed HTML

```
<a href="Javascript:PostRating('','|P|621','D')">D</a>a href="Javascript:PostRating('','|P|622','+0')">+0</a>-D
```

**More Context:**

I have a string that needs to have a replace done on it.  This is existing code so I'm not in a position to rework the function.

The original string is: `+0-D`

This string gets passed into the function below multiple times looking for matches and then if it finds a match it will replace it with the value (also passed in as a parameter).

When the `+0-D` gets passed in the first time the `+0` is matched and a replace is done: `<a href="Javascript:PostRating('','|P|622','+0')">+0</a>`

Then the next time the string is passed in: `<a href="Javascript:PostRating('','|P|622','+0')">+0</a>-D`.  The function finds the `D` as a match and it looks like it attempts to do a replace.  But it is on this pass that the string gets jumbled.

Ultimately what I'm expecting is this:

`<a href="Javascript:PostRating('','|P|622','+0')">+0</a>-<a href="JavaScript:PostRating('','|P|622', 'D')">D</a>`

This is what I'm currently getting after the 2nd attempt:

```
<a href="Javascript:PostRating('','|P|621','D')">D</a>a href="Javascript:PostRating('','|P|622','+0')">+0</a>-D
```

**Further Context:**

The `+0-D` is one of many strings this function handles.  Some are very simple (i.e. Just +0), others are much more complex.

**Question:**

Based on the above, what do I need to do to get the regex to not jumble the string?

Comment: This looks overly complicated. What is your desired output?

Comment: @CAustin - I updated my question with more information.  I can't rewrite the function at this time.  I am however interested in what I can do so that the 2nd replace doesn't jumble the string.  Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regular expressions. That's what the DOM is for

Comment: @DanielBeck - This string is one of many strings.  They aren't all +0-D.  So the input string isn't always this simple.  This string is just causing an issue as the string is being returned out of order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the escfind:

```
escfind = "\\" + find;
var regexp = new RegExp(escfind,"i");
var match = regexp.test(str);
```

The first thing I did was in the 2nd replace clause I created a new RegExp to not use the `"\\" + find;`

```
                if((find !== aTagText) && (aTagText.indexOf(find) < 0)){
                    try{
                        var regexp2 = new RegExp(find,"i");
                        var match2 = regexp2.test(str);
                        console.log(str.replace(regexp2,rep));
                    }catch(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                }
```

Then my string began to return as expected, however, when I opened it up to all the variations I was getting the *Unexpected quantifier* error.

Then I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923652/why-regexp-generates-an-error-of-unexpected-quantifier-on-ie8) - which lead me to escape out my find:
Once I replaced my code with this:

```
escfind = find.replace(/([*+.?|\\\[\]{}()])/g, '\\$1');
```

Then I got the output as expected:

```
<a href='+0'>+0</a>-<a href='D'>D</a>
```