# Typescript Validators Pattern RegEx Unexpected Quantifier Error in Internet Explorer, but works in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

The following code snippet is causing Internet Explorer to throw an `Unexpected Quantifier error`, but Chrome is working just fine

```
sicmessage: new FormControl('', [
   Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(300), 
   Validators.pattern(new RegExp(/(?=(?:^\w))([A-Za-z ]+)(?<=[^ ])$/))
]),
```

The error is:

> SCRIPT5018: Unexpected quantifier

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why RegExp generates an error of "unexpected quantifier" on IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923652/why-regexp-generates-an-error-of-unexpected-quantifier-on-ie8)

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern uses lookbehind, which wasn't added to JavaScript until ES2018. IE11 doesn't and never will have that feature.

If you need a lookbehind, you might use the [XRegExp library](http://xregexp.com) by Steven Levithan, which supports them (and compiles to native regex). He also has an [article](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript) about how to mimic lookbehind when it isn't supported.

---

Side note: There's no reason to pass a regular expression into the `RegExp` constructor (anymore¹). The `/.../` syntax creates a regular expression, so just remove the `new RegExp(` and `)`.

---

¹ "anymore" - People used to do this because of a caching bug in a couple of JavaScript engines, but that was fixed years and years ago. People also sometimes use it when the expression has the global flag in order to reset `lastIndex`, but it's a lot less work to just do `x.lastIndex = 0` instead in that case. Your expression doesn't use `g`, so that doesn't apply to you.